# How to generate a Node.js flame graph on CentOS?

Tags: node.js, centos

I'd like to [generate a flame graph for my node.js app](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/). Unfortunately, my dev box is OSX (doesn't support utrace helpers, per the linked article) and my production box is CentOS (doesn't even have dtrace).

I've found some indication that something like [SystemTap might be a dtrace alternative](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/14/systemtap-dtrace-for-linux/), but I've been unable to cobble together an effective working way to generate the appropriate stacks.out file to feed into stackvis.

Does anybody know of a decent tutorial on how to get this up and running? I'd prefer it on CentOS (so I can examine my production app) but OSX would also be sufficient.

Comment: The first link is broken. This one maybe? http://dtrace.org/blogs/dap/2012/01/05/where-does-your-node-program-spend-its-time/

Comment: @cuberoot that's a good article, too. The official Node.js blog article was the one I was linking to, though, and it appears to be down. Here's the cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:VDDdPeBezdMJ:blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 2):

From the latest google searches, people are unhappy with SystemTap on Centos, but here is an article http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2012/03/17/linux-kernel-performance-flame-graphs/ that was referenced by someone's FlameGraph github project https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph

I would say move towards the real solution, of getting dtrace installed rather than relying on the work around.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, the perf_events profiler can be used to sample stack traces, and has JIT symbol support. For node.js, you need to be running version 0.11.13 or higher, with the v8 option --perf-basic-prof. That option creates a /tmp/perf-PID.map file for symbol translation, which perf uses. Once you have perf profiling stack traces with JavaScript symbols, you can then create flame graphs using stackcollapse-perf.pl (from the FlameGraph repo) on the output of "perf script".

I wrote up the full instructions here: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-09-17/node-flame-graphs-on-linux.html